# How to export one row selection to JSON using MySQLi and prepared statement

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am working on the below code. How can I export the result of one row in JSON?

I tried this like

```
$arr = [];
$arr = $stmt->get_result()->fetch();
```

but I am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT id, name, email, phone FROM users WHERE id = ?');

$userId = 1; // or $_GET['userId'];

$stmt -> bind_param('i', $userId);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> store_result();
$stmt -> bind_result($id, $name, $email, $phone);
$stmt -> fetch();
```

Comment: How does the first code block (with the $arr variable) relate to the second code block (with the $stmt variables)? When are you trying to call get_result in relation to the other code below?

Comment: What PHP version you are using? It must be long in the past if it doesn't have get_result()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using a very old PHP version, probably PHP 5.3. I strongly recommend to upgrade to a recent version as soon as possible.

Once you have upgraded, you can use the following.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id, name, email, phone FROM users WHERE id = ?');
$userId = 1; // or $_GET['userId'];
$stmt->bind_param('i', $userId);
$stmt->execute();
$json = json_encode($stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc());
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a useful example in the php documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Based on that example, here's what I recommend for you:

```
$results = array();
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT id, name, email, phone FROM users WHERE id = ?');
$userId = 1; // or $_GET['userId'];

$stmt -> bind_param('i', $userId);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> bind_result($id, $name, $email, $phone);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $results[] = array(
        "id"=>$id,
        "name"=>$name,
        "email"=>$email,
        "phone"=>$phone
    );
}
$stmt->close();
$output = json_encode($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);

$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name, email, phone FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$sth->execute([ $userId ]); // or $_GET['userId'];
$dbUser = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($dbUser);
```

If you project is `API` use:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); // For CORS
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Consider proposing a [better connection code](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql). With your current code json_encode() will return null if there are non-latin characters in the data. A proper connection charset, as well as other essential options must be configured during connection.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm using `$db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");` for non latin characters. I worked with data in several languages(Russian,German), but I never had any problems

Comment: The question is not what you are using personally but what you are proposing in your answer. That said, using exec() is the wrong way to set the charset, it must be configured using the designated parameter in the DSN.